# How to display Json Response in input checkbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, jquery

I am using below code get json response -

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="test_name" value=""></label>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(this.responseText,undefined, 2).replace(/\\n/g, "").replace(/\\r/g, "")
                                                                                      .replace(/\\/g, "")
                                                                                      .replace(/^"/, "")
                                                                                      .replace(/"$/, "");
    var jsonobj =  JSON.parse(jsonstr);

    for ( var i=0;i<jsonobj.length; i++) 
    {
         console.log(jsonobj[i].Test_Name);
             var label = document.getElementsByName('test_name')[0]; 
             label.value= jsonobj[i].Test_Name;               
    }; 

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://testendpoint/", true);
  xhttp.send();

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting response as below -

```
[{
"Test_Name": "FOOD",
"Code": "PE"
},
{
"Test_Name": "FOOD_TRAVEL",
"Code": "PE"
}]
```

I need to pass the `Test_Name` into the below tag -

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test_name" value=""></label>
```

How to loop all the `Test_Name` and display.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for :

```
var jsonstr = '[{ "Test_Name": "FOOD",  "Code": "PE" }, { "Test_Name": "FOOD_TRAVEL", "Code": "PE" }]';

var jsonobj =  JSON.parse(jsonstr);
for ( var i=0;i<jsonobj.length; i++) 
    {
         console.log(jsonobj[i].Test_Name);

    };
```

This gives the following output:

FOOD
FOOD_TRAVEL

Modified : So now I can see your element within the label as Checkbox.
A checkbox can have a Boolean value to check/uncheck the Checkbox.
You need to use the right element to assign a value like a Label, TextBox etc

```
for ( var i=0;i<jsonobj.length; i++) 
    {
         console.log(jsonobj[i].Test_Name);
             var label = document.getElementsByName('test_name')[0]; 
             label.value= jsonobj[i].Test_Name;               
    };
```

Here is how you will assign the value :

So if you want to generate checkboxes dynamically.
Here is the code.
Modify you element to have a wrapper div.

```
<div id="wrapperfortestnames"></div>
var gencheckboxes = "";
for ( var i=0;i<jsonobj.length; i++) 
        {
             console.log(jsonobj[i].Test_Name);
                 gencheckboxes = gencheckboxes + '<input type="checkbox" name="test_name" value="'+ jsonobj[i].Test_Name; +'">' + jsonobj[i].Test_Name + '<br></input>';
        }; 
var dwrap = document.getElementById('wrapperfortestnames');
dwrap.innerHTML=gencheckboxes;
```

Cheers

Comment: That i am getting in the response. But i need to assign those values into <label><input type="checkbox" name="test_name" value=""></label> and display it. There will be a lot of Test_Name.

Comment: I have updated my modified code above. I am unable to display the values..I am getting the values in console log. Can u check.

Comment: var label = document.getElementsByName('test_name')[0];  is giving only the first test_name. How to display all the name..

Comment: Still i am unable to see checkboxes in the UI on button click. I am seeing the inputcheckbox in console log not in UI.. Is it not rendering on button click.

Comment: Please paste your current code .Will review and fix